# Render lit / lit-html TemplateResult as string

Tags: lit-html, lit

In lit/lit-html/lit-element, a standard component is the TemplateResult (usually HTMLTemplateResult), created like:

```
function renderMe(msg) {
    return html`<div>Hello ${msg}!</div>`;
}
```

and of course the power and efficiency of the library is that subsequent calls will reuse the same `<div>` Element and only replace the changed fragments.

For testing the `renderMe()` function above, however, it would be helpful to be able to see the return value as a standard string, like:

```
assert.equal(RENDER_AS_STRING(renderMe('kimiko')), '<div>Hello kimiko!</div>');
```

and fix any bugs in the function before testing how it renders into the browser itself.

Is there a function like `RENDER_AS_STRING` either in lit itself or in a testing library?  I have searched and not found one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of execution contains `html strings` and `values` that alternate:

[image]

We can combine them in the same order:

```
function renderMe(msg) {
    return html`<div>Hello ${msg}!</div>`;
}

const getRenderString = (data) => {
  const {strings, values} = data;
  const v = [...values, ''] // + last emtpty part
  return strings.reduce((acc,s, i) => acc + s + v[i], '')
}

console.log(getRenderString(renderMe('SO')))
```

You can test it in [the playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy50cyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudH0gZnJvbSAnbGl0JztcblxuZnVuY3Rpb24gcmVuZGVyTWUobXNnKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgPGRpdj5IZWxsbyAke21zZ30hPC9kaXY-YDtcbn1cblxuY29uc3QgZ2V0UmVuZGVyU3RyaW5nID0gKGRhdGEpID0-IHtcbiAgY29uc3Qge3N0cmluZ3MsIHZhbHVlc30gPSBkYXRhO1xuICBjb25zdCB2ID0gWy4uLnZhbHVlcywgJyddIC8vICsgbGFzdCBlbXRwdHkgcGFydFxuICByZXR1cm4gc3RyaW5ncy5yZWR1Y2UoKGFjYyxzLCBpKSA9PiBhY2MgKyBzICsgdltpXSwgJycpXG59XG5cbmRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKCdvdXRwdXQnKS50ZXh0Q29udGVudCA9IGdldFJlbmRlclN0cmluZyhyZW5kZXJNZSgnU08nKSkgIFxuXG5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-XG48aGVhZD5cbiAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPVwibW9kdWxlXCIgc3JjPVwiLi9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmcuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8cCBpZD1cIm91dHB1dFwiPjwvcD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0)

And the [recursive](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy50cyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudH0gZnJvbSAnbGl0JztcblxuZnVuY3Rpb24gcmVuZGVyTWUobXNnKSB7XG4gICAgcmV0dXJuIGh0bWxgPHA-SGVsbG8gJHttc2d9ITwvcD5gO1xufVxuXG5mdW5jdGlvbiByZW5kZXJCbG9jayhtc2cpIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gaHRtbGA8ZGl2PiR7cmVuZGVyTWUobXNnKX08L2Rpdj5gO1xufVxuXG5jb25zdCBnZXRSZW5kZXJTdHJpbmcgPSAoZGF0YSkgPT4ge1xuICBjb25zdCB7c3RyaW5ncywgdmFsdWVzfSA9IGRhdGE7XG4gIGNvbnN0IHYgPSBbLi4udmFsdWVzLCAnJ10ubWFwKGUgPT4gdHlwZW9mIGUgPT09ICdvYmplY3QnID8gZ2V0UmVuZGVyU3RyaW5nKGUpIDogZSApICAgICAgXG4gIHJldHVybiBzdHJpbmdzLnJlZHVjZSgoYWNjLHMsIGkpID0-IGFjYyArIHMgKyB2W2ldLCAnJylcbn1cblxuZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoJ291dHB1dCcpLnRleHRDb250ZW50ID0gZ2V0UmVuZGVyU3RyaW5nKHJlbmRlckJsb2NrKCdTTycpKSAgXG5cblxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPC9oZWFkPlxuPGJvZHk-XG4gIDxwIGlkPVwib3V0cHV0XCI-PC9wPlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ) version

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';

function renderMe(msg) {
    return html`<p>Hello ${msg}!</p>`;
}

function renderBlock(msg) {
    return html`<div>${renderMe(msg)}</div>`;
}

const getRenderString = (data) => {
  const {strings, values} = data;
  const v = [...values, ''].map(e => typeof e === 'object' ? getRenderString(e) : e )      
  return strings.reduce((acc,s, i) => acc + s + v[i], '')
}

document.getElementById('output').textContent = getRenderString(renderBlock('SO'))
```

Comment: Wonderful answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that this does not totally work because the values can themselves contain Templates so need a recursive solution.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert, you can test it now.

Answer (score 2):

@Daniil Loban's answer works great if the arguments are strings, but if they might themselves be TemplateResults or arrays of TemplateResults (which are all allowed by spec), it needs a more complex answer:

```
export function template_as_string(data) {
    const {strings, values} = data;
    const value_list = [...values, ''];  // + last empty part
    let output = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        let v = value_list[i];
        if (v._$litType$ !== undefined) {
            v = template_as_string(v);  // embedded Template
        } else if (v instanceof Array) {
            // array of strings or templates.
            let new_v = '';
            for (const inner_v of [...v]) {
                new_v += template_as_string(inner_v);
            }
            v = new_v;
        }
        output += strings[i] + v;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This does not cover where lit allows binding to attributes without surrounding the interpolation in quotes: `<img src=${srcValue} />`.

Comment: right -- at present it also doesn't cover if one of the values is null or undefined (which cannot have properties read of it).